# Make local point to new git repository

Tags: github, git-rebase

I must say that I am a beginner as far as Git is concerned. I may get a few terminologies and keywords wrong. So, please bear with me.

I have 2 different machines with somewhat similar codebase linked to 2 different git repositories respectively. a -> A, b->B. I would like the codebase on both the machines to point to the same repository. How do I achieve this without causing any modification to the files on either machine. Once, the 2 repositories are linked, I want to be able to push, pull and commit to and from the same repository on both my machines. Please advise.

Comment: You want to merge the history of two repositories, that don't share any history so far?

Comment: I don't really care about the history! I just should be able to access the same repository from all my machines and do all the functions like push pull commit

Comment: Why don't you clone the same repository on both machines?